# Group an Array of Vectors according to certain Floors in Three.js

Tags: vector, 3d, three.js

I have a list of Vectors which represent points on three different floors in three.js.

I am trying to group these vectors according to the floor they belong to. Is there a good formula to do this? Perhaps find height from on vector or something. Not sure how to go about this. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Rob

Comment: Did you at least try something? Can you share the code that you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Wilt said... Can't really help *you* without more info.

Still, if your floors are even and all stand on the xz plane (in my example), You may indeed check the points' height (position.y) against the floors'.

```js
var container, renderer, scene, camera, controls;
var floors = [];
var points = [], materials = [], heights = [];

init();
animate();

function init() {

    // renderer
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        antialias: true,
        alpha: true
    });
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    container = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(container);
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    // scene
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // camera + controls
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
    camera.position.set(0, 50, 750);
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    controls.autoRotate = true;

  //floors
 for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
    var planeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(500, 500, 10, 10);
    var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0xffffff * Math.random(),
        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
        transparent: true,
        opacity : 0.3,
        depthWrite : false //get rid of coplanar glitches wall/floor
    });
    materials.push(planeMaterial);
    var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);
    plane.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
    //plane.rotation.y = Math.PI / 8;  //Uncomment to see this doesn't work if the floors move, i.e. changing rotation/position. If this is what you need, just raycast from point to floor in the animation loop and count how many floors the ray goes through (intersects.length)
    plane.position.y = 75*i;
    heights.push(plane.position.y);
    floors.push(plane);
    scene.add(plane);
    }
    
    //wall
    var height = heights[2];
    var planeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(500, height+100, 10, 10);
    var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0xffffff * Math.random(),
        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
        transparent: true,
        opacity:0.3,
        depthWrite : false //get rid of coplanar glitches wall/floor
    });
    materials.push(planeMaterial);
    var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);
    plane.position.y = heights[1]+45;
    plane.position.z = -510/2;
    scene.add(plane);
    
        // points
    for (i=0; i<200; i++) {
    var sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(3, 32, 16);
    var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry);
    sphere.position.x = Math.random() * 500 - 250;
    sphere.position.y = Math.random() * 300 - 100;
    sphere.position.z = Math.random() * 500 - 250;
    scene.add(sphere);
    points.push(sphere);
    }   
   
    // events
    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
}

function onWindowResize(event) {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

function addSpheres() {
    //addSpheres
    for (i=0;i<200;i++) {
    var that = points[i].position.y;
     points[i].position.y = ( that < heights[0] ) ? 200 : that - 0.5;
      if ( that > heights[0] && that < heights[1] ) points[i].material = materials[0];
      if ( that < heights[2] && that > heights[1] ) points[i].material = materials[1];
   if ( that > heights[2] ) points[i].material = materials[2];
     points[i].material.needsUpdate = true;
      
    }
}

function animate() {
    controls.update();
    addSpheres();    
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

```html
<script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Now, feel free to "group" these points according to your needs.
Please note that "vectors" are different from "points". [Read more about the difference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/645672/what-is-the-difference-between-a-point-and-a-vector).

Raycasting would be the way to go if you had a more complex scene (moving floors/different planes, points moving in different directions).